# Chrome don't print error if syntax error in worker.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If I have a syntax error in a worker.js file, I see no error in Chromium's browser, just the worker is never run. This is **really** annoying, since my only way to debug is to comment parts of my code until some basic `console.log` get printed. For instance, I lost like 30mn to realize I replaced a `:` with a `;` in a `case` statement (or I use firefox but sometimes the code is a module which seems not to be compatible with firefox).

Am I missing something? (running 109.0)